# Separating a list of dicts

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I've been trying to find a way to take a data collection that contains three fields where two of the fields can contain multiple items and convert/expand that data to a list where a row is added for every item in one of the fields.

The data is about kubernetes pods and the containers and images inside them.  I can get the raw data just fine I just can't transform it.

the json data is this:

```
  - name: condense the raw data
    set_fact:
      pod_data: "{{ pod_data|default([]) + [{'pod_name':item.pod_name,'container_name':item.container_name,'image_path':item.image_path }] }}"
    with_items: "{{ podinfo | json_query('resources[*].{pod_name: metadata.name, container_name: spec.containers[*].name, image_path: spec.containers[*].image }') }}"

  - debug: var=pod_data

"pod_data": [
        {
            "container_name": [
                "container1",
                "container2"
            ],
            "image_path": [
                "path1",
                "path2"
            ],
            "pod_name": "pod1"
        },
        {
            "container_name": [
                "container3",
                "container4"
            ],
            "image_path": [
                "path3",
                "path4"
            ],
            "pod_name": "pod2"
        }
```

I want to output the data in a 1:1 format like this:

```
"pod_data": [
        {
            "container_name":  "container1"
            ,
            "image_path": "path1"
            ,
            "pod_name": "pod1"
        },
        {
            "container_name": "container2"
            ,
            "image_path": "path2"
            ],
            "pod_name": "pod1"
        },
        {
            "container_name": "container3"
            ,
            "image_path": "path3"
            ,
            "pod_name": "pod2"
        }
```

I'm not good enough with loops to know how to do a nested style loop when there are multiple sub elements in ansible.  I could do it in powershell but that doesn't help me here.

Is my only choice some sort of include_tasks loop while passing each item and container/image count so I can split it that many times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the structure

```yaml
  pod_data_update: |
    [{% for i in pod_data %}
    {% for n,p in i.container_name|zip(i.image_path) %}
    {container_name: {{ n }}, image_path: {{ p }}, pod_name: {{ i.pod_name }}},
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}]
```

, convert it from YAML, and update *pod_data*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        pod_data: "{{ pod_data_update|from_yaml }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  pod_data:
    - {container_name: container1, image_path: path1, pod_name: pod1}
    - {container_name: container2, image_path: path2, pod_name: pod1}
    - {container_name: container3, image_path: path3, pod_name: pod2}
    - {container_name: container4, image_path: path4, pod_name: pod2}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    pod_data:
    - container_name:
      - container1
      - container2
      image_path:
      - path1
      - path2
      pod_name: pod1
    - container_name:
      - container3
      - container4
      image_path:
      - path3
      - path4
      pod_name: pod2

    pod_data_update: |
      [{% for i in pod_data %}
      {% for n,p in i.container_name|zip(i.image_path) %}
      {container_name: {{ n }}, image_path: {{ p }}, pod_name: {{ i.pod_name }}},
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}]

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        pod_data: "{{ pod_data_update|from_yaml }}"
    - debug:
        var: pod_data|to_yaml
```